# Machine learning for traffic sign recognition

Tags: programming, machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, patternmatching

I am working on a project and I need to detect traffic sign. Given my limited experience with machine learning and deep learning, I was wondering if someone could point me to any open project or library to do it?

Basically I need a ML blackbox that gets an image (of the traffic sign) and returns a text corresponding to what it is. I'm not a ML guy myself so any types of information would really help.

Comment: If you are willing to pay for it, MATLAB would be perfect for this.

Comment: @AidenGrossman pay is fine, but I need something being able to run with bash script, and in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You should find some useful information in the article at https://autottblog.wordpress.com/programming-the-car/opencv/ which links to a [repo](https://github.com/task123/AutoTT).

Also for anything OpenCV and Deep Learning I strongly recommend reading Adrians blog at [pyimagesearch](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/) as it gives you a really good grounding in both.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using MATLAB for this kind of analysis. The documentation in MATLAB is superb, and they already have tutorials for doing just this sort of thing. MATLAB also allows you to do transfer learning, so you can take an already existing deep neural network and fine tune its weights in order to make your model applicable to your use case without spending a bunch of time training your model. Within MATLAB, you can easily load datasets, and trying convolutional neural networks. They have several tutorials on there website to do this. I also believe that they have a self driving car toolbox if you are trying to design that sort of system. However, MATLAB is not cheap if you are doing this for s commercial application. However, if you are a student and using this for educational purposes, you will be able to get MATLAB with the toolboxes you need for probably less than $100. MATLAB also has support for Linux, and I believe you are able to run MATLAB scripts from the command line.

Comment: If it can run with command line, it would be awesome!

Comment: You can run matlab files from the command line. Take a look at this stackoverflow article:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657005/matlab-running-an-m-file-from-command-line.